# Unmarshaling nested json string use json.RawMessage

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to unmarshal a raw json string that was from a previously unmarshaled json byte array. I have the current code:

```
type Message struct {
    Event string
    Data json.RawMessage  // how data is parsed depends on the event
}

type CreateMessage struct {
    id int
}

var evt = []byte(`{"event": "create", "data" :{"id":5 }}`)

func main() {
    var message Message
    log.Println(string(evt))
    json.Unmarshal(evt, &message)

    log.Println(message)
    log.Println(message.Event)
    log.Println(string(message.Data))
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", message)

    var message2 = new(CreateMessage)
    err := json.Unmarshal( message.Data, &message2 )

    log.Println(message2)
    log.Println(err)
}
```

And the output is:

```
2015/06/29 23:22:10 {"event": "create", "data" :{"id":5 }}
2015/06/29 23:22:10 {create [123 34 105 100 34 58 53 32 125]}
2015/06/29 23:22:10 create
2015/06/29 23:22:10 {"id":5 }
{Event:create Data:[123 34 105 100 34 58 53 32 125]}
2015/06/29 23:22:10 &{0}
2015/06/29 23:22:10 <nil>
```

Why can't I unmarshal data as a `CreateMessage` object? I tried the example [here](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage.UnmarshalJSON) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101954/go-json-unmarshal-nested-object-into-string-or-byte) but they don't unmarshal the nested raw json data and that is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is simply that the `id` field of the `CreateMessage` struct is unexported, it starts with a lowercase letter. Change it to:

```
type CreateMessage struct {
    Id int
}
```

And it will work.

**Notes:**

Since `message2` is already a pointer (`new(CreateMessage)`), you don't have to pass its address to `json.Unmarshal()`, its value is enough:

```
var message2 = new(CreateMessage)
if err := json.Unmarshal(message.Data, message2); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
log.Printf("%+v", message2)
```

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 &{Id:5}
```

Or don't use `new()` at all:

```
var message2 CreateMessage
if err := json.Unmarshal(message.Data, &message2); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
log.Printf("%+v", message2)
```

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 {Id:5}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Bjg6Wg_ACP).

Also note that now the name of the field is `"Id"` and JSON contains `"id"` but the `json` package is "intelligent" enough to match them (same with `"Event"` and `"event"`). But know that if you would ever try to marshal your structs, the output would contain `"Id"` and not `"id"`.

If you want to use a completely different field name or make sure it will be lowercased when you marshal your structs, you can use [struct tags](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Tag) to tell how it should appear in the JSON text, for example:

```
type CreateMessage struct {
    MyId int `json:"id"`
}
```

Comment: Well, I feel dumb. I am fairly new to go if that wasn't obvious. Thank you very much for the very detailed answer. I knew the difference between exported fields but I guess I didn't make the connection that that was the problem here.